# Is it possible to tell my Siri to connect my iPhone to a bluetooth speaker? "Hey Siri, play some Jazz on the SoundBot Bluetooth speaker!"

Tags: bluetooth, siri, speakers

Note that my SoundBot Bluetooth speaker will not be connected beforehand to my iPhone. It will be on, paired, but not connected. I want to tell my iPhone Siri to connect to and play on the bluetooth speaker. Is that possible?

EDIT:

The speaker is on. It is just not connected to the iPhone. It is the iPhone that connects to the speaker, not the other way around. Siri is running on the iPhone that wants to connect to the speaker. The speaker and iPhone have been previously paired

Comment: “Connect to” would be the issue here. If the speaker is off, there’s no way to turn on.  If they are on, they aren’t connected and if not connected, how do you send a command to them?  It’s a chicken/egg problem.

Comment: @Allan The speaker is on. It is just not connected to the iPhone. It is the iPhone that connects to the speaker, not the other way around. Siri is running on the iPhone that wants to connect to the speaker. The speaker and iPhone have been previously paired.

Comment: Previously paired ≠ currently connected.